# Linear operator $A: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Linear operator $A: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ such as $A^3$ — projection operator. What eigenvalues could $A$ has? Is it correct that $A$  will have diagonal matrix in some $\mathbb R^n$ basis?

My solution is:
$A^3$ - projection operator. Let's consider eigenvalue $\lambda$ and a corresponding eigenvector $v$ of the operator $A$. Then by definition of the eigenvalue and eigenvector one has:
$$Av = \lambda v$$
One has $A^3$ that is operator projection: $P^2 = P$. On the other hand according to the eigenvalues properties: $A v = \lambda v \Rightarrow A^k v = \lambda^k v$.
In our case one can right it as*: $A^6 v = \lambda^6 v \Leftrightarrow A^3 v = \lambda^3 v$, then one gets $\lambda^6 - \lambda^3 = 0 \Rightarrow \lambda_1 = 0, \space \lambda_2 = 1$
As a result there are 2 possible eigenvalues of the operator $A$: $\lambda = 0$ и $\lambda = 1$*.

* If a projection is nontrivial it has minimal polynomial $x^2-x=x(x-1)$, which factors into distinct linear factors, and thus $P$ is diagonalizable. The eigenvalues of a projection matrix must be $0$ or $1$. [[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra))].

Let's consider now the second part of the task. Diagonal matrix exists when all eigenvectors are linearly independent (all eigenvalues are different or geometric multiplicity equals to the algebraic). In this case as eigenvalues of $A$ are just $0$ or $1$, the following is possible:

- eigenvalues are **repeated** (set of $0$ and $1$) and geometric multiplicity equals to the algebraic.

What could I have missed in this solution if any?

Comment: I don't understand the problem statement.  Is $A^3$ a projection operator?.  Or is $A^3$ - projection operator ... something?

Comment: $A^3$ is a projection operator such that $(A^3)^2 = A^3$

Comment: There could be complex eigenvalues such that $\lambda^3 = 1$ (a priori)

Comment: I do not understand your final assertion. You are asked whether $A$ is diagonalisable and you seem to say "Yes it is possible". But there are examples of $A$ even in dimension $2$ which are not diagonalisable.

Comment: A rotation matrix of angle $2\pi/3$ in the plane is such an example.

Comment: @Gribouillis The question is about real operators on a real space so there are no non-real eigenvalues. There may be non-real roots of the characteristic equation but that is a different matter.

Comment: @ancientmathematician You can embed ${\mathbb R}^n$ in ${\mathbb C}^n$. The real matrix $A = \begin{pmatrix}-1/2&-\sqrt{3}/2\cr \sqrt{3}/2& -1/2\end{pmatrix}$ has complex eigenvalues satisfying $\lambda^3=1$. If $A^6=A^3$ in $\mathbb R$, then $A^6=A^3$ in $\mathbb C$.

Comment: @Gribouillis Of course you can complexify but that changes the problem completely. It's a common misttake.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I don't see where it is a mistake. It helps understand the structure of the solutions.

Comment: @Gribouillis You have made a mistake regarding the definition of an "eigenvalue" in this context. It is helpful to consider the complex "eigenvalues" of a transformation over a real vector space, but these values are not technically "eigenvalues" according to the actual definition of the word.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: there is a basis of $ {\mathbb{R}}^{n}$ where the matrix of
$ A$ is a block diagonal matrix containing only blocks of the
following forms

\begin{equation}
\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}\boxed{\begin{array}{ccc}1&&\\
&\ddots &\\
&&1
\end{array}}&&&&\\
&\boxed{0}&&&\\
&&\boxed{\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\
0&0
\end{array}}&&\\
&&&\boxed{\begin{array}{ccc}0&1&0\\
0&0&1\\
0&0&0
\end{array}}&\\
&&&&\boxed{\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\
{-1}&{-1}
\end{array}}
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}

Comment: thanks for the example. however, from my solution and the properties of the eigenvalues I have got that $\lambda = -1$ is not a part of the solution, isn't it?
if it is, why so? thanks!  
besides that the example is valid as an example of $A$ having a diagonal matrix in some $\mathbb{R}^n$ basis

Comment: $\lambda=-1$ is never an eigenvalue. The above matrix is not an example. I'm only saying that in a certain basis of ${\mathrm R}^n$, the matrix of $A$ can be written as a [block-diagonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix) which diagonal blocks are a various number of blocks like these ones. This matrix is not diagonal because of the three last kinds of blocks.

Comment: maybe to draw a line: such a diagonal matrix does exist. and it is just a combination of $0$ and $1$ on the diagonal such that their multiplicities match, isn't it?

Comment: a 3d example:
$$\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}$$

Comment: @FeliksHarbar Such a diagonal matrix does not always exist. Also your example is a particular case with only blocks of the first and the second kinds on the diagonal. Simply take the linear operator in ${\mathbb R}^2$ which matrix in the canonical basis is $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\ -1&-1\end{pmatrix}$. There is no basis where this operator has a diagonal matrix.